# Javascript - img onload firing before image is loaded

Tags: javascript, image, onload

My img.onload seems to be firing before the image is loaded.  I am attempting to draw the images on a canvas.

Here is my code:

```
var tileAtlas = [ ];


function loadAtlasJSON() {  
    for (var i = 0; i < JSONpaths.length; i++) {
        loadJSON( 
            {
                fileName: JSONpaths[ i ],
                success: function( atlas ) {            
                    console.log(atlas.id);
                    addToTileAtlas( atlas );
                }
            } 
        );
    }
};


function addToTileAtlas( atlas ) {
    atlas.loaded = false;
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
        // Logs way too soon from the previous console.log
        console.log(atlas.id);
        atlas.loaded = true;
        console.log(atlas.loaded);
    };

    // Always returns false, so onload has not fired yet
    console.log(atlas.loaded);
    img.src = atlas.src;

    // Store the image object as an "object" property
    atlas.object = img;
    tileAtlas[ atlas.id ] = atlas;
}
```

After this code, I use keep checking each atlas's .loaded until all are true.  When they are all true, I draw the images on a canvas, but nothing is shown.

But if I set a timeout (say 1000 ms) before drawing the images, the images are drawn fine.  This leaves me to believe that .onload is firing before the images are actually loaded.

Furthermore, I think the timestamps of the log are too close to each other to account for the loading time of each image, which are 20-90 kb.

```
[16:12:06.209] "ground"
[16:12:06.210] false
[16:12:06.211] "ground-collision"
[16:12:06.211] false
[16:12:06.213] "objects-collision"
[16:12:06.213] false
[16:12:06.223] "ground"
[16:12:06.223] true
[16:12:06.224] "ground-collision"
[16:12:06.224] true
[16:12:06.225] "objects-collision"
[16:12:06.225] true
```

I know that the function assigned to the onload is NOT invoked immediately, since the `console.log(atlas.loaded);`
under the img.onload assignment still returns false.

I have checked this in multiple browsers that I know do not hold a cache of the image.  In my main browser, Firefox, I have set `network.http.use-cache` and `browser.cache.offline.enable` to false.

I am testing this code on a localhost apache server using MAMP, but I don't know if that is relevant.

Since I know using a timeout to delay the display of the images works, that also means the JSON loading and img.src paths are correct.

Since img.onload fires too soon, I can only think of a couple causes:

1. The browser has the image cached and thus sees it as loaded.  But then this doesn't explain why it won't display the image even when refreshed.
2. My .onload syntax/usage is incorrect.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: And where are you displaying it?

Comment: On an HTML5 canvas.  Sorry, should have stated that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the issue.  It was a bug due to asynchronous loading of my tileAtlus array.  I was for in looping over an array that was still undefined.  Going to have to re-evaluate my approach.  Thanks!